# Using a variable in ng-repeat and passing it to a controller

Tags: angularjs, amazon-dynamodb, ngroute

I have created an AngularJS app that contains two columns: one for a menu and a second for content (each link in the menu links to). The content and menu is in a table in DynamoDB that I am scanning with a Lambda function. The output of this function is being consumed as a JSON response with the following structure:

```
{
    "body": [{
        "course-content": "RL front matter",
        "course-video": "https://123-course-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/vid_1.mp4",
        "course-id": "rcl",
        "course-title": "sml",
        "course-lesson": "Lesson One"
    }, {
        "course-content": "RL2 front matter",
        "course-video": "https://123-course-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/vid_2.mp4",
        "course-id": "rcl2",
        "course-title": "sml",
        "course-lesson": "Lesson Two"
    }, {
        "course-content": "RL3 front matter",
        "course-video": "https://123-course-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/vid_3.mp4",
        "course-id": "rcl3",
        "course-title": "sml",
        "course-lesson": "Lesson Three"
    }]
}
```

I (with the help of the great folks here) built the following controller that loops through the response and builds the menu:

controller

```
app.controller('menu', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('api address').
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.navi = response.data.body;
            $scope.selectCourse = function(course, index, path) {
            console.log(path)
            $scope.content = response.data.body[index]
            console.log($scope.content)
          };

                });
});
```

menu built using ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="nav in navi">
    <ul><li>{{ nav['course-lesson'] }}
        <button ng-click="selectCourse(nav, $index, '/content/' + 
        $index)">Select</button>
    </li></ul>
</div>
```

This build the following menu:

```
Lesson One <button>
Lesson Three <button>
Lesson Two <button>
```

And I am using a second controller that consumes the content from the same api call:

```
app.controller('content', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('api address').
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.content = response.data.body;

        });

});
```

content is displayed in a route with a simple content.html template as follows:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/", {
    templateUrl : "templates/main.html"
  })
  .when("/content/:id", {
    templateUrl : "templates/content.html",
    controller : "content"
});
```

**Updated: Here is where I still need help:**

1. How do I pass/use the $index variable in the menu controller to the content controller so the content updates as needed in the right template when I click on each button?

To help better understand the functionality:

- Lesson One links to content for lesson one - lesson one content is
  displayed in the content template.
- List item Lesson Two links to content for lesson two - lesson two content is
  displayed in the content template.
- List item Lesson Three links to content for lesson three - lesson three content
  is displayed in the content template.

Sorry for the long post, but I wanted to provide enough detail to help clarify any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass data to a controller from an `ng-repeat` element, use the `ng-click` directive:

```
<div class="col-4" ng-controller="menu">
    <div ng-repeat="nav in navi">
    <ul>
       <li>
          {{ nav['course-lesson'] }}
          <button ng-click="selectCourse(nav, $index)">Select</button>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Assign the function to scope:

```
$scope.selectCourse = function(course, index) {
    console.log(course, index);
};
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-click Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

Comment: Thanks - that works just about like needed, except I dont have a content link on each menu item to fire the router so the content from each link is pushed into the content controller and template. Can that be done in the new $scope.selectCourse function as well? Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Ok, Im making progress - Ill update the post in a few mins.

Comment: This answers the question of how to use a variable in `ng-repeat` and pass it to a controller. Questions about navigating to a different view should be submitted as a new question.